# Кракозябры в PL/SQL Developer

Tags: кодировка, oracle

Доброго всем времени. Вопрос, думаю, несложный будет для Вас. Открываю PL/SQL Developer БД запросом и в текстовых полях отображаются кракозябры? Как победить? Лезть в настройки БД через Oracle Configuration Assistant или же в девелопере настройка?

Answer (score 7):

Ошибка в вашей настройке языка. Клиент Oracle берет настройку языка из виндовой переменной NLS_LANG, если я правильно помню, ее нужно установить в значение  RUSSIAN_AMERICA.CL8MSWIN1251.

Сделать в Винде это можно в "Свойствах системы", закладка "Дополнительно", кнопка "Переменные среды". Добавляете этот параметр, если он не создался клиентом Oracle и задаете значение.

Comment: Спасибо большое, поменял, помогло!)
Только небольшая поправочка - это меняется в ключе реестра, а где именно можно узнать из Developer-a: "Help - > Support Info -> Registry"

Comment: Я точно правил через переменные среды, про реестр тоже слышал. Возможно, разные версии клиента воспринимают разные способы для установки значения.

Comment: Коллеги, порядок применения настроек следующий. Если значение NLS_LANG изменено в реестре, то сначала используется оно, но если создана переменная окружения, то она сильнее, и имеет приоритет. 
Так можно запускать разные приложения bat-файлами с разными настройками, делая `set nls_lang=...` 
Ну а после того как клиентсое приложение уже запустилось, оно может само выдать `ALTER SESSION` и менять `nls_language` и `nls_territory` сколько угодно раз. 
То же касается и большинства других NLS-настроек, и не только.

Answer (score 2):

Русский текст (кирилица) в клиенте Oracle (PL/SQL Developer и др.)

Установить параметр реестра (выполнить -> regedit.exe):

```
Путь: HKLM\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_OraClient10g_home1
Параметр: NLS_LANG = AMERICAN_RUSSIA.CL8MSWIN1251
```

Код для reg файла:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_OraClient10g_home1]
"NLS_LANG"="AMERICAN_RUSSIA.CL8MSWIN1251"
```

Путь и содержимое ветки реестра вашего oracle клиента, можно узнать из PL/SQL Developer-a:

```
"Help - > Support Info -> Registry"
```

Answer (score 2):

Для Казахстана на казахские буквы:

В реестре `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Oracle`

```
NLS_LANG = AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8MSWIN1252
```

В переменной среде:

```
NLS_LANG = AMERICAN_CIS.AL32UTF8
```

Answer (score 1):

Переменная окружения действительно помогает, но ее значение должно быть несколько иным.

1. Сначала нужно включить проверку соответствия кодировки клиента и сервера. Это делается так: Tools -> Preferences -> Options -> Check for client & server character set mismatch
2. После этого при подключении вы увидите предупреждение вида "NS_LANG is not defined...", что означает, что переменная не определена или же там будет указано, что переменная определена, но ее значение не соответствует правильному. Вот это правильное и нужно вписать, чтобы заработало.